# Display unescaped URLs in the Chrome address bar

Tags: google-chrome, url, escaping

I have whitespaces in some local files. Is there a possibility, for example an addon, to change the way the URLs of such files are represented in Chrome’s address bar?

For example instead of

```
file:///C:/Javascript/MDN%20→%20Destructuring%20Assignment%20(Doc).html
```

I would prefer to see

```
file:///C:/Javascript/MDN → Destructuring Assignment (Doc).html
```

Of course, when I copy the URL I want the escaping to stay.

Firefox does it this way.

Comment: No. You are making the URLs invalid by unescaping the escaped characters. They are escaped for a reason.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility, for example an addon, to change the way the URLs of such files are represented in Chrome’s address bar?

No. Chrome extensions do not have any control over the way URLs are displayed in the address bar.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this is not possible using addons.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched back to Firefox.

Comment: No need to downvote, so far the only solution that works.